# Conducting a t-test with a grouping variable

Tags: r, dataframe, syntax, anova

Getting started on an assignment with R, and I haven't really worked with it before, so apologies if this is basic.

`brain` is an excel dataframe. Its format is as follows (for an odd 40-some rows):

```
para1 para2 para3 para4 para5 para6 para7
FF 133 132 124 118 64.5 816932

highVAL = ifelse(brain$para2>=130,1, 0)
```

highVAL gives me a vector of 1's and 0's, categorized by para2.

I'm looking to perform a t-test on the mean para7 between two sets: rows that have para2 > 130 and those that have para2 < 130.

In Python, I would construct two new arrays and append values in, and perform a t-test there. Not sure how I would go about it in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closer than you think! Your `highVAL` variable should be added as a new column to the `brain` data frame:

```
brain$highVAL <- brain$FSIQ >= 130
```

This adds a true/false column to the dataset. Then you can run the test using `t-test`'s formula interface:

```
result <- t.test(MRIcount ~ highVAL, data = brain)
```

Comment: I've added it (taking your code) to the data frame, and when I run the code and get to that line, I get an error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "highIQ", value = logical(0)) :   replacement has 0 rows, data has 40.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose your error without a reproducible example. Can you provide the data in your question? Use `dput(brain)` and paste the result.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the real variable names present in your data set. The use of `ifelse` was also unnecessary, since all you really need is the true/false result given by the logical comparison (the line that creates `highVAL`). The formula interface for `t.test` is basically saying, "`MRIcount` is the dependent variable, `highVAL` is the independent variable, and both can be found in `brain`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm hitting a new error now. I'll post my output to the original post again. I guess this is where I'm confused. I'm working in RStudio, and to execute code, I'm highlighting the block I want to run, and hitting CTRL+r. Not sure why I'm getting the errors I am.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing `ifelse`, which is a specialized function, with standard `if`, which is a conditional statement that uses `{ }` braces. Still, that conditional looping is unnecessary. Once you have the `highVAL` column added to `brain`, you can run the t-test as shown in my solution. If your professor is expecting you to use a loop, that's neither my problem nor a good way to do it. ;-)

Comment: Also, @jdobres, just want to confirm a 2 sample t-test is correct in this case, as opposed to a 1-sample t-test?